# Center a div in a container, and have the div be the width of its child

Tags: html, css, margin

I want a `<div>` to be the size of its child element, but I also want to center it within a containing `<div>`. How can I do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/xjCGM/1/

In that jsfiddle I try do `display: inline-block` and `margin: auto` but they don't work together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `text-align: center`: http://jsfiddle.net/xjCGM/2/ (and you'll most likely use `text-align: left` on the element itself)

Answer (score 1):

Add `text-align:center;` to the `.container` div

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xjCGM/3/)**